# Building ksmbd on Debian Buster (+bpo)

Tags: compiling, kernel-modules, cifs

I am trying to build the ksmbd kernel module. I tried the tag version:

```
$ wget https://github.com/namjaejeon/ksmbd/archive/refs/tags/3.2.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz 3.2.1.tar.gz
$ cd ksmbd-3.2.1
$ make
[...]
  CC [M]  /tmp/ksmbd-3.2.1/transport_tcp.o
/tmp/ksmbd-3.2.1/transport_tcp.c: In function ‘create_socket’:
/tmp/ksmbd-3.2.1/transport_tcp.c:484:10: error: incompatible type for argument 4 of ‘sock_setsockopt’
          (char __user *)iface->name,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As well as the version from git/master:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:namjaejeon/ksmbd.git
$ cd ksmbd
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.10.0-0.bpo.7-amd64/build M=/tmp/ksmbd modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-0.bpo.7-amd64'
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '/tmp/ksmbd/ksmbd_spnego_negtokeninit.asn1.c', needed by '/tmp/ksmbd/ksmbd_spnego_negtokeninit.asn1.o'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-0.bpo.7-common/Makefile:1845: /tmp/ksmbd] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-0.bpo.7-common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-0.bpo.7-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:47: all] Error 2
```

What's the trick to generate those *.asn1.c files ?

[For reference](https://github.com/namjaejeon/ksmbd/blob/master/Makefile#L29-L32):

```
$ cat Makefile 
[...]
$(obj)/asn1.o: $(obj)/ksmbd_spnego_negtokeninit.asn1.h $(obj)/ksmbd_spnego_negtokentarg.asn1.h

$(obj)/ksmbd_spnego_negtokeninit.asn1.o: $(obj)/ksmbd_spnego_negtokeninit.asn1.c $(obj)/ksmbd_spnego_negtokeninit.asn1.h
$(obj)/ksmbd_spnego_negtokentarg.asn1.o: $(obj)/ksmbd_spnego_negtokentarg.asn1.c $(obj)/ksmbd_spnego_negtokentarg.asn1.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Fedora and RHEL, the `ksmbd` external module build works because the `kernel-devel` packages ship all the relevant tools, in particular `asn1_compiler`.

There is no equivalent package in Debian, so the only way to build `ksmbd` is to use the full kernel source, and the simple option is to [build it in the kernel tree](https://github.com/namjaejeon/ksmbd#installing-as-a-part-of-the-kernel):

```sh
sudo apt install linux-source-5.10
cd $(mktemp -d)
tar xf /usr/src/linux-source-5.10.tar.xz
cd linux-source-5.10/fs
git clone https://github.com/namjaejeon/ksmbd
```

Make the necessary changes to `fs/Kconfig` and `fs/Makefile`, then

```sh
cd ..
make allmodconfig
make fs/ksmbd/ksmbd.ko
```